# Simple Building for a C++ Hello World

Tags: c++

So I am trying to learn C++ while going through the Facebook Puzzles.
To test if submittals to the Puzzle Master are working properly, the [meepmeep](http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php?puzzle_id=3) program can be used.

> The input file will contain ASCII text that is going to be completely ignored by your program. In fact, do not even bother opening up the file, it will just complicate things.
>
> The output should be the string "Meep meep!" (without the double quotes, using exact capitalization) followed by a single newline (don't forget this part!).

Sounds simple enough. Got everything working the first time around and just use the inbuilt compiler that came from XCode

```
g++ meepmeep.cpp -o meepmeep
```

Send that in and the robot said there are errors so I thought maybe I am not building this properly.

Made a makefile by searching around for how to do makefiles

```
meepmeep: meepmeep.cpp Makefile
    $(CXX) -o $@ $<
```

Still no luck robot would not accept. Of course there could be coding errors/syntax I am not seeing

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Meep meep!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**So I am building this right or not ? What is the proper way to build ?**

My compiler version is 4.2.1

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5664~105/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
```

Could it be that I am not using 4.2.3 ? or the architecture ? (The main question is still the first ... Is the build right or not)

If the code is not right that would be awesome. I wish it is that easy.

I don't want to know how the robot checks it or what tests it uses, please don't tell me. I just want to know if it is a legit build/code so I can go the next step and ask the Puzzle Master about it.

Comment: you seriously don't even list the errors reported?

Comment: @Jonathan As given by the Facebook Puzzle Robot "I unfortunately found some bugs and determined it to be incorrect. You may resubmit a new solution if you want to try again. The exact bug(s) that I found cannot be explained to prevent others from using the grading system as a debugging tool and gaining an advantage over others." on my computer I had no errors, I could have a bug. The Robot is a shared resource so I cannot keep sending it files it will clog up the system for others.

Comment: Perhaps the robot system is down for maintenance or something? The code is OK except you don't need to include [fstream], you don't need the `main` arguments, and you don't need the `return 0;` (because C++ `main` returns 0 by default). By the way, where do you find the puzzles, and where do you submit solutions?

Comment: @Alf The Robot is up just may not be testing properly ? (It was down earlier this week) Yeah I included the `fstream` because it was talking about using files but not doing anything with them. So having it there is def not needed, I will try changing the return.Thanks. The link with the puzzles http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php and the instructions for submittal are there as well.

Comment: What exactly are you attaching to your email submission?  Given your description, I would try attaching meepmeep.cpp and Makefile (with those filenames).

Comment: @aschepler oh okay my filename for Makefile was makefile and the last time I attached all three so maybe it just tested the meepmeep executable ? I sent this time with just meepmeep.cpp and Makefile I wouldnt be able to tell you for a next four hours though ( the results are every fours or so I think) Thanks

Comment: You need to be careful with makefiles: the second line needs to begin with a tab and not spaces.  You can check that with `cat -vt Makefile`, which will display "^I" where tab appears.

Comment: @Tony thanks yeah I figured that out when first making the file it gave an error `Makefile:2: *** missing separator` when I did spaces at first.

Comment: @phwd: yup - just worried that depending on how you sent the file (e.g. cutting and pasting from some terminal programs into a mail program can do that), you may have reintroduced spaces.  I'm not sure how the Robot accepts submissions, but just something to be careful with.

Comment: @aschepler alright success for using the Makefile and the source cpp file. I still would like to try with an executable sometime when I get gcc 4.2.3 working . Thanks for all the help.

Comment: An executable won't work.  When you compile C++, you get something that can only be executed on a particular type of computer (Darwin, Windows, Linux, etc.) and even then only if compatible libraries are installed.  So the Robot probably won't be able to execute it at all.  When the Robot says you may submit an executable file, it's talking about interpreted languages like Perl or Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `gcc` version 4.2.1. The Facebook puzzle page you linked to [explicitly states](http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php?puzzle_id=3) in its *Submission directions* that it only accepts `gcc` **4.2.3**.

Darwin is a *NIX environment, so that's not the problem, but you should definitely upgrade your compiler, because the support libraries won't be the same and your program won't work.

Comment: The code posted should compile and run correctly with both gcc 4.2.1 and 4.2.3.  For compiled languages (including C++), looks like the robot should accept a Makefile and c++ source as attachments.

Comment: édéric Yeah I figured so. I was trying to upgrade earlier in week but the latest on the mac is 4.2.1 (based on XCode Tools from the DVD ?) Is there a way to have both 4.2.1 and 4.2.3 with 4.2.1 as default I really dont want to mess up Xcode in anyway. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @phwd, I guess you could do that by downloading, compiling and installing 4.2.3 yourself in a non-system prefix (e.g. `~/phwd/gcc-4.2.3`), then explicitly invoke that gcc when compiling puzzles. That's how I'd do it under Linux, I think.

Comment: édéric Thanks much I will try that I wouldn't be able to tell you for a bit if it worked I think it took 30-45 mins to install gcc last time.